# OC4J and Weblogic WNA and Form Authentication

Tags: java, active-directory, weblogic-10.x, jaas, oc4j

Currently in one of our customer's environment we have our applications running on both OC4J (10g) and Weblogic (10.3.6). Both applications are using basic Form Authentication to the DataBase. Our Java environment is still on `1.4` for OC4J and `1.6` for Weblogic.

They gave us a new requirement recently, which is to implement Single-SignOn (SSO) against their Windows Active Directory server, including auto-logon. And also to remain the use of the Form Authentication for non-ActiveDirectory users.

**Questions**

Is it possible for this SSO implementation and our current Form Authentication to co-exists?

Configuring Weblogic should be straightforward. But for OC4J, is it necessary to use other OracleAS components such as the Oracle Internet Directory?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do that. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13977_01/configwna.htm) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will go through the document.